# How to run Symfony Bundle without setting up Symfony app?

Tags: symfony, bundle

I have created a standalone Symfony bundle now is it possible to run the bundle alone without setting up Symfony?

I have performed unit tests and it is ok now I want to run the controller of the bundle in the browser (is it possible?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Bundle is Symfony specific and it only makes sense in a Symfony context.

The only context I can think of when it might be useful to call bundle controllers without installing the bundle in a Symfony project is **tests**. If that's what you're after, it is possible to set up a stripped down Symfony kernel just for tests. See my article on the subject: [How to run Behat scenarios and functional tests from a Symfony bundle in isolation of a project](http://zalas.eu/run-behat-scenarios-and-functional-tests-from-symfony-bundle-in-isolation-of-project/)

I have also implemented a [DemoBundle](https://github.com/jakzal/DemoBundle) where you can see it working with both phpunit and Behat tests.

You can take the same approach if you simply need to test your bundle manually in a browser, but you don't really want to install the whole framework.

Bottom line is you need to set up at least a minimal Symfony kernel.

Comment: Glad to know about Behat, but I was looking for if it was possible to run the controller (from Browser window) as it would with Symfony setup. 
Now, it seems that it's not possible. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I did mentioned in my answer it is possible by creating a simple kernel. You failed to explain your use case though.

Comment: Ok, to be specific, I have my bundle at https://github.com/santhapa/NepaliDateConverterBundle and I have also created AppKernel. So, can I get the functionality of this bundle alone without setting up Symfony. (not with testcase)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a bundle inside Symfony context without letting know Symfony that it is "installed". To do so, you have to enable bundle in your `AppKernel`:

```
// app/AppKernel.php

// ...
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...,
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        );

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, if I have not explained my question properly. What I mean is I have created a standalone bundle now, can I run the bundle alone without setting dummy symfony application.

Comment: What do you mean by "standalone bundle"? Bundle is meant to be run in Symfony, it cannot be standalone.

Comment: Thanks for reminding "Bundle is meant to be run in Symfony". I just want the features of my bundle to run without setting up Symfony. I will be looking to your answer.